# Is there any advantage in defining a synchronous function as async and await it?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Suppose I have a function with the following definition:

```
def f(x, y):
    sum = x + y
    return sum
```

and I use this function in another coroutine like g:

```
async def g():
    .
    sum = f(2, 3)
    .
```

Is there any benefit in definig f as a coroutine and await it in g or the result is the same?

```
async def g():
    .
    sum = await f(2, 3)
    .
```

Comment: I don't think there's any benefit. Async should be used for things that are actually asynchronous.

Comment: @ Barmar, so in your opinion, is it ok to use sync function f in async function g?

Comment: Presumably you're using synchronous functions *all the time* within `async` functions, no? If you're just calling `str()`, you've used a synchronous function within an `async` one. If there's no compelling reason to make `f` `async`, then don't.

Answer (score 2):

The difference it makes is twofold:

- The additional `await` introduces a "break" in your code in which other async tasks have a chance to execute; your async tasks shouldn't be so long-running that this makes any practical difference, but there you have it.
- You're preparing your code for async execution, which makes a difference if you pass `f` as a callback:

  ```
  async def g(f):
      sum = await f(2, 3)
  ```

  Even if `f` isn't asynchronous now, you can refactor it to be asynchronous in the future and the interface will keep working without changes. Whether this makes any practical sense for you is up to you to decide.

Comment: Never used asyncio so there is a question, how await f() will provide another break point if there is nothing yielding in f function?

Comment: @Javed. Nevermind, I guessed out that await will return coroutine which will be called on another eventloop loop, makes sense

Comment: @deceze, could you explain more about the "break" part? I was thinking to something similar. If I define f as async when awaiting it, the control is returned to the event loop. So other coroutines have a chance to execute. But when it is a sync function, all this time, other coroutines are waiting for f to finish. Is it true and if so, Doesn't that help overall?

Comment: The `await` expression itself suspends the execution of `g`. I have to admit I'm not entirely sure whether any other coroutine could or would be scheduled to execute between that suspension and the evaluation of the `f` coroutine. Please take that with a grain of salt.

Comment: In your second bullet point, the function "f" must return an awaitable object or else you will get an exception.  Typically that means that f must be a function declared with "async def", but there are other possibilities as well.  It's a little confusing to say that you are preparing your code to be asynchronoous; in fact you are REQUIRING it to be asynchronous.